# call class in external class

Tags: android, class

i create class contain functions . but i want add AsyncTask class in this class and class in MainActivity but i dont know how i can do it :(

external class :

```
public class Function {

    public Context mContext;
    public Activity mactivity;

    public Function(Context _context, Activity _activity)
    {
        mContext = _context;
        mactivity = _activity;
    }

 public class GetJson extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(JSONObject getJson){

        }
    }
```

i know i can call method with this :

```
Function _func = new Function(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.this);
_func.someFunction();
```

but i dont know how call class.

this code return error

```
_func.GetJson.execute();
```

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. What error is being returned to you?

Comment: You don't call classes, you instantiate( create an instance of the object they describe) them and call methods defined in the class. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: i use this comde but return error _func.GetJson.execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks from scrappedcola i found answer .

```
public class Function {

    public Context mContext;
    public Activity mactivity;

    public Function(Context _context, Activity _activity)
    {
        mContext = _context;
        mactivity = _activity;
    }

 public void runGetJson(){
        new GetJson().execute();
    }

 public class GetJson extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(JSONObject getJson){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `_func.GetJson.execute();` because `execute()` it's not a static method, and you are calling it like that.

You should create a GetJson object and call `execute()`. You should make `GetJson` static if you want to create an object outside Function.

My advice, if you are going to create an inner Class that extends `AsyncTask` do it in the class you are going to use to execute it. If you can't because you want to execute the `AsyncTask` in more than one class then make a class just for that AsyncTask.